# If the call stack gets corrupted, would that crash only the current thread, or my entire application?

Tags: c#, assembly, multithreading, callstack

I'm a noob when it comes to threading in C#, and I'm not sure if each thread is supposed to have its own call stack? Basically, if I get a "Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly " , would that crash only the thread in which it occured, or the entire program?

Comment: You would get this error only in the debug build.  It is a bug in your code, detected by the C/C++ runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each thread has its own stack, so stack corruption will only *directly* affect a single thread.  But the default thread exception handler will take down the application.

Comment: Phew, that's a relief:) For a moment I thought I won't be able to handle a crashing thread:)

Answer (score 0):

Each thread has its own call stack, so corruption will only directly affect a single thread.

But as pointed out by John, this may be sufficient to halt the program.